# Indexing two user type information in one collection in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

We have two tables. One is normal `users` tables where we are storing the normal user information this table we can say as a base table. And another is `user_staff` table which is also having different table but with `user_id` as a reference to user table.

Virtually saying the users and user_staff are almost same set of data but we are keeping this in different table since user table having master data and staff table having user_staff data.

While we are indexing this data in solr, we would like to keep all these users and `user_staff` in a single collection but we have to keep an additional key in each collection to mention the type like `master`, s`ub-account`, `user`. But if we are usig this in a single collection how we can keep a connection of `users_staff` to `user` table as we do in mysql in solr?

Comment: Why can't you index those that has `user_staff` as a single `user` document as well? There shouldn't be any reason to have two documents from what you're describing.

Comment: Keep in mind that in Solr, unlike a relational database, it's very normal and useful to denormalize information. You could store all users in a single Solr collection and include the additional attributes from your `user_staff` table on the documents representing staff users and omit them from documents representing non-staff users.

Comment: Store all data related to a user (content from both `user` and `user_staff`) in a single Solr document. There is little advantage to having two documents linked by a common id - this will make almost all Solr operations more expensive. Denormalize into a single, flat document.